# Magento 1 - add inline javascript to product page via layout update xml code

Tags: javascript, xml, magento, layout

Hi i want to use google analytics's AB-Testing engine. Therefore i have to add a javascript-snippet to single product pages.

My intend was to add it in the description or short-description. It is working, but it is insufficient, because the script makes a redirect, which means the page loads half and then is redirected.

Google says i should add the script in the head-tag. Is it possible to insert the script as "custom layout update" here:
[image]

i could imagine something like

```
<default translate="label" module="page">
        <label>All Pages</label>
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
                <action method="addJs"><script>alert('hello')</script></action>
            </block>
        </block>
</default>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's cleaner to load the javascript from file. You do not necessarily need all that blocks but can do it like:

```
<default translate="label" module="page">   
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>path/to/script.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Path is relative path from `js` folder in magento root.

To add javascript to xml directly (which I do not recommend) you can use CDATA, like:

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="your.block.name">
        <action method="setText">
            <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">alert('hello');</script>]]></text>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: but the js is unique for each product.. i dont want to add files for each

Comment: for which block should i do the settext? i dont want to remove the rest of the head block

Comment: You can add your own custom block for that purpose. Edited my answer to give you example code.

Comment: This is only for Magento 1, adjusted the title. For Magento 2, you should ask a different question.

Answer (score 1):

my solution was to extend the head block:

```
<?php
class Company_Modulename_Block_Html_Head extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head {
    public function addInlineJs($name)
    {
        $this->addItem('inlinejs', $name);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getCssJsHtml()
    {
        $html = parent::getCssJsHtml();

        foreach ($this->_data['items'] as $item) {
            if($item['type']=='inlinejs') {
                $html .= sprintf('<script type="text/javascript">%s</script>' . "\n", $item['name']);
            }
        }

        return $html;
    }
}
```

now i can use it like that

```
<reference name="head">
       <action method="addInlineJs"><script>alert('cool');</script></action>
</reference>
```